# Scripting sudo via SSH behaves strangely when reading from file

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I've discovered that I can run a single sudo command on a remote system from within a bash script. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t <REMOTE_IP> 'sudo ls /root'
```

However, if I try to run the same command via a loop over a file containing the IPs of the remote systems it starts to get weird. It fails to allocate a TTY with the -t option so I use two (-t -t). Doing this gets it to the password prompt. It then tells me my password was incorrect when I didn't even enter one, displays a second prompt which echos my password back and then hangs after I hit enter.

An example of such a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read i
do
    ssh -t -t $i "sudo ls /root"
done < ip.list
```

Example of the results I'm seeing:

```
user@opensuse:~/bin> ./test.sh 
10.153.171.131

[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: Pa55w0rd
^CKilled by signal 2. *This is where it hangs and I have to kill it.*
```

I haven't found much in the way of an explanation so if anyone can shed some light on this I'd be most grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirecting `stdin` inside your loop:

```
while read i
do
    ssh -t -t $i "sudo ls /root"
done < ip.list
```

This means that (a) `ssh` is no longer connected to your TTY, and (b) it's probably going to eat your input.  Ideally, you would redirect input to ssh from `/dev/null` and configure `sudo` to not require a TTY.  However, you can try:

```
ssh -t $i "sudo ls /root" < /dev/tty
```

Comment: The `-n` option for ssh redirects input to /dev/null

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be what I needed. I'll have to look into disabling requiretty in the sudoers file. I'm not entirely sure if we have it there by default or if we were required to. It would certainly make things easier not having to deal with it.

Comment: You should just replace `while read i` with `for i in $(<ip.list)`